# How do I use the "sum If" function, based on identical text, to sum consecutive cells together, but ignore all other non-consecutive examples?

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet which has numerical entries either two or three times daily.
I cannot predict if it will be two or three entries per day. 
One is an "opening" count and one is a "closing" count. 
I need to sum both.

Each row starts with the current date.
The rest of the row has the figures associated with that date.

I'd like a way to automatically sum up those figures based on their having identical dates.

This is on Google Sheets, but I imagine this is the same with Excel.
I've been able to figure out the "sumif" function before but only for adding totals from the totals of a set, never dynamic like this.
Pretty big noob.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question with some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: you can use COUNTIF() to count if you have 2 or 3 cells that day and create a SUM() accordingly

Comment: So use sumifs() with the date criteria